# Not able to scrape information from a website using lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to scrape data of user review beer on beeradvocate.com to analyze user attitude towards different of beer type. But I can only  have result of the first few page, remain is empty

Situation:

- There are 500 different type of beer, each beer has different number of rating and reviews
- Site only show 1 page of results for guest, to see all the information, you need to login

My approach

- Get the beer link, number of rating of each beer to define range of loop for each beer
- Login using request session and post

```
def review_scrape (beer_link, number_of_ratings):
    reviews=[]
    rate =[]
    for pages_i in range(0,int(number_of_ratings),25): #site shows 25 resulst/page
        session = requests.session() # Start the session
        payload = {'login':'suzie102', 'password':''}
        page1 = session.post("https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/login/login", data=payload) 
        url = beer_link+'/?view=beer&sort=&start=%d'%(pages_i)
        page1= session.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        soup1 = lxml.html.fromstring(page1.text)
        rate_i = soup1.xpath('//span[@class = "muted"]/text()')[8::3]
        print(url)
        reviews_i = soup1.xpath('//div/text()')
        reviews.append(reviews_i)
        print(len(reviews))
        rate.append(rate_i)
    return rate,reviews
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: always put result as text, not image

Comment: first check what you get in HTML when it can't find data - you can save in file and open in web browser. Maybe you get HTML with warning for bots/script or with captcha.

Comment: It looks like you want to start here: https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/styles/ - no login requirement that I can see but it uses cloudflare so requests is likely to not work. Consider selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update, thanks to everyone comment, I tried to use it with selenium to scrape. It works now

```
def webstite_scrape_p2 (beer_link, number_of_ratings):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/sam/Downloads/chromedriver')
    url = 'https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/login/'
    driver.get(url)
    
    loginelement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@class="xenForm formOverlay"]//dd//input[@name ="login"]')))
    loginelement.send_keys('suzie102')

    pwelement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@class="xenForm formOverlay"]//dl[@class ="ctrlUnit"]//dd//ul//li[@id = "ctrl_pageLogin_registered_Disabler"]//input[@name ="password"]')))
    pwelement.send_keys('')

    page_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@class="xenForm formOverlay"]//dl[@class ="ctrlUnit submitUnit"]//dd//input[@type ="submit"]')))
    page_click.click()

    rate = []
    reviews =[]
    avg_user =[]
    for link, i in zip(beer_link, number_of_rev): 
        for pages_i in tqdm(range(0,int(i),25)): #site shows 25 resulst/page)
            new_url = link+'?view=beer&sort=&start=%d'%(pages_i)
            print(new_url)
            driver.get(new_url)
            
            #print(driver.find_element_by_name("hideRatings").is_selected())
            #check_box = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@style="display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;"]//input[@type = "checkbox"]')))#check_box.click()
            #check_box.click()
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.get(new_url)
            page_source = driver.page_source
    
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
        
            rate_i = [ i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all('span', class_ = "muted")][8::3]
            rate.append(rate_i)
            
            reviews_i = [ i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all('div')]
            reviews.append(reviews_i)
            
            avg_i = [i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all('span', class_= "BAscore_norm")]
            avg_user.append(avg_i)
    return rate, reviews, avg_user
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one problem that ive see.

```
 url = beer_link+'/?view=beer&sort=&start=%d'%(pages_i)
```

/ is redudant, what you need is
url = beer_link+'?view=beer&sort=&start=%d'%(pages_i)

that is why there are //?view in your print of links.

I can see that there are anchor links "next" leding to next page. I would recommend while loop or recursion.

Other than that, I cant see what is missing from your script. Everything else looks in order and it should work.

If you could give us more details, we might have more to work with.

Comment: Hi, I tried to obmit the "/", but nothing happens :(. More information is my password 'Beer@addiction102', beer_link = ''https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/32184/124777/" and my number_of rating is 127